# Creating a Virtual Machine from a physical Disk

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I recently added a 4th hard disk to my computer installed Windows 8 Pro with Microsoft development tools, all went fine, I'm happy.

I have in my computer another disk with Windows 7 full of Embarcadero/CodeGerar/Borland tools, i.e. Delphi, which I would prefer not to install in my newly installed OS.

When I work on Delphi stuff I boot to that Win 7 disk and work there, when I work on Visual Studio I boot to the W8 disk and work there.
But I rather prefer to always boot to Windows 8, and open a Virtual Machine with the Delphi stuff to work temporary (not surprisingly I work more in VS than in Delphi these days).

I already use VirtualBox to run an eval of Windows Server 2008, the processor of my computer couldn't support the new Hyper thingy from microsoft, but I'm very happy with the product, I don't miss Microsoft's virtual machine, at all.

So I wonder if I can access that physical disk from within a Virtual Machine, or at least a tool that creates a Virtual HD based on a physical disk.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) will create a VHD from a physical hard drive.  I don't use VirtualBox, but it appears to be compatible.